# $X \sim N(0,1)$, what is the distribution of $X | X > 0$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am trying to find $E[X | X> 0]$, and in doing so, I know (according to the book solution below) I should integrate
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x N(0,1) dx
$$

where you observe the lower limit is 0. But is this suggesting that the conditional pdf of $X|X>0$ is just the right half of $N(0,1)$? But this doesn't seem to make sense because this pdf only integrates to 0.5.

Generally, I know that

$$
E[X | Y = y] = \int_{X_{\min}}^{X_{\max}} x f_{X|Y=y}(x)dx
$$

So I am trying to find how this general definition relates to the one above.

---

Book solution:

[image]

Comment: Err, $U(0,1)$ is always greater than 0 anyway, so the conditioning doesn't do anything. Did you mean normal or something other than uniform?

Comment: @TodorMarkov Oops yes, it should be normal not uniform!

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int_0^{\infty} x N(0,1)dx$?

Comment: You just want to calculate $\int_0^{\infty} x f_{X|X>0}(x)dx$, so it remains to compute $P[X \leq x|X>0]$ and take the derivative to get $f_{X|X>0}(x)$.

Comment: @Michael that integral is apparently $E[X | X > 0]$. It seems $f_{X | X>0} = N(0,1)$ based on the above?

Comment: @Michael I just updated the OP with the solution from the book I am reading. It seems the book's solution is incorrect?

Comment: The book solution is incorrect, note that $E[X|X>0] \neq \int_0^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$. Also the notation $-1/2x^2$ is unclear, they really mean $-x^2/2$.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, makes sense. Is $E[X | X > 0] = E[|X|]$? I have seen the latter $E[|X|]$ computed the same way as what the book used for $E[X | X >0]$.

Comment: You can consider the random variable $X$ that can take only two values, with $P[X=-1]=P[X=2]=1/2$.  Now you can directly compute and compare $E[X|X>0]$ and $E[|X|]$.

Comment: @Michael It seems I get the same value, i.e., $E[X | X > 0] = E[|X|]$. I also tried monte carlo and seem to get the same.

Comment: They are not the same. How are you computing? Clearly $E[X|X>0]=2$ since if $X>0$ then it must be 2. How are you computing $E[|X|]$?

Comment: @Michael Oh, sorry, I was referring to the case where $X \sim N(0,1)$. For your case, they are different and $E[|X|] = 1.5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requested density is

$$\frac{1}{1-\Phi_X(0)}\phi_X(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}\phi(x)=2\phi(x)$$

...the integral to calculate the conditional expectation is trivial

**Further details of the explanation.**

As per definition, with continuous distributions

$$F(x|x>0)=\frac{\mathbb{P}[X \leq x;X>0]}{\mathbb{P}[X>0]}=\frac{F_X(x)-F_X(0)}{1-F_X(0)}$$

Derivating the conditional CDF you find the conditional density...

$$f(x|x>0)=\frac{1}{1-F(0)}f(x)$$

As in the standard normal law $1-F(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ the conditional density is

$$f(x|x>0)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

$x>0$

In order to calculate the expectation you have to solve

$$\mathbb{E}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{+\infty}{xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}}_{=1}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

the integral is 1 without any calculation because the integrand is a Rayleigh distribution. If you want to calculate it....it is trivial. In fact

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}=-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\Bigg|_{0}^{+\infty}=1$$

...that's all

Comment: I don't understand this, can you expand what you wrote? Isn't the integral the first equation I had?

Comment: @dd22205 : look at my edit

Comment: hmm, maybe my confusion is because the book I am looking at has $E[X | X>0] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-0.5x^2)dx = 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, which is twice as small as your derivation

Comment: I got your answer when I did monte carlo. I just pasted the book's solution in the OP. It seems they did it wrong?

Comment: @dd22205 : The solution of your book looks wrong to me. In fact, by definition, $\mathbb{E}[X|B]=\int x f(x|B)dx$ where B is an event. The function they used for $f(x|B)$ is not a density because its integral is 0.5

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. That's why I was so confused when I originally posted this. But your answer makes sense to me.

Comment: What if you were finding $E[|X|]$ in this case. Would the answer be the same as $E[X | X> 0]$?