# What is the difference between $X^+$ and $X | X > 0$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

I am confused between $X^+$ and $X | X > 0$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430229/correlation-between-positive-and-negative-part-of-a-random-variable) we see the usage of $X^+$

where $X^+ \max(0, X)$. And we see that $E[X^+] = \int_0^{\infty}x N(0,1)dx = 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799968/x-sim-n0-1-what-is-the-distribution-of-x-x-0?noredirect=1#comment7832637_3799968)

we see $E[X | X > 0] = \int_0^{\infty} x * 2 \cdot N(0,1)dx = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ where $f_{X | X > 0} = 2 \cdot N(0,1)$.

We also can find that the latter case $E[X | X > 0] = E[|X|]$.

But I am confused here by what is the difference between $X^+$ and $X | X > 0$? They seem to be the same thing, but obviously their expectations are different by a factor of 2 (assuming they're computed correctly)

Comment: I have no idea what $X|X>0$ means, can you give the definition? I only know what $E[X|X>0]$ means

Comment: @CalvinKhor. Yeah, I wasn't sure how to really phrase that part, but by $X | X > 0$, I essentially just mean the positive part of $X$.

Comment: In which case, you've defined $X|X>0$ to be exactly the same as $X^+$, but this is not what people mean when one writes $E[X|X>0]$: this is a conditional expectation, not an expectation of a random variable called $X|X>0$

Comment: Is $X^+$ a random variable here? When we do $E[X^+]$, this to me reads "Expectation of positive part of $X$. When we do $E[X | X > 0]$, this reads to me "Expectation of X given that X is positive," which seems to be equivalent to saying "Expectation of positive part of $X$".

Comment: Yes, $X^+ := \max(X,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X^+ = \begin{cases} X, & X > 0 \\ 0, & X \le 0. \end{cases}$$  Whereas, $$X \mid X > 0 = \begin{cases} X, & X > 0 \\ \text{undefined}, & X \le 0. \end{cases}$$  If we let $Y_1 = X^+$ and $Y_2 = X \mid X > 0$, then the support of $Y_1$ is $\mathbb R$, but the support of $Y_2$ is $\mathbb R^+$.  This means there is a discrete probability mass for $Y_1$, specifically $\Pr[Y_1 = 0] = 1/2$.  $Y_1$ can be thought of as a left-censored variable:  values of $X$ less than or equal to $0$ are observed as $0$.  $Y_2$, on the other hand is a left-truncated variable:  values of $X$ less than or equal to $0$ are never observed at all.

---

A simple example may be in order.

Suppose I have a fair six-sided die with faces numbered from $1$ to $6$ inclusive.  I roll the die but you can't see it.  All you know is what I tell you about the outcome.

In the first scenario, I tell you in advance that if I roll a number less than $3$, I will report the result as $3$.  What is the resulting probability distribution that you observe?

In the second scenario, I tell you in advance that if I roll a number less than $3$, I do not report the result, but instead re-roll the die until I obtain a number that is at least $3$, at which point I report that value.  You are never told whether I re-rolled.  What is the resulting distribution of outcomes you observe?

> In both scenarios, I have access to the complete information about the outcomes, so what I observe is discrete uniform on $\{1, \ldots, 6\}$.  But what you observe in the first scenario is not this.  Instead, the outcome is $3$ with probability $1/2$ and $4$, $5$, or $6$ each with probability $1/6$.  In the second scenario, you observe a discrete uniform distribution on $\{3, 4, 5, 6\}$, each with probability $1/4$.

Comment: Does $Y_1$ have a joint pmf-pdf? For $X^+ > 0$, it seems it should be a pdf?

Comment: If you are asked explicitly for the expectation of the *positive* part of $X$, should that be $E[X^+]$ or $E[X | X > 0]$? Struggling with the wording, but I feel like it could go either way

Comment: @dd22205 Yes, $Y_1$ is "mixed" in the sense that it is partly discrete and partly continuous on its support.  As for your other question, I would never use such vague language.  I would either say, "expectation of the maximum of $X$ and $0$," or "expectation of $X$, given $X$ is positive."  The phrase "positive part of $X$" is unclear.  The most similar language I can compare it to is "the fractional part of $X$," in which case I would say if $X < 0$, the "positive part" is $0$, suggesting $X^+$ as the meaning.  But this is not at all obvious or a precise use of language.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $E[X|A]=\frac  {E[XI_A]} {P(A)}$. So $E[X|X>0]$ is nothing but $EX^{+}$ divided by $P(A)$ where $A=(X>0)$. Note that $P(A)=\frac  1 2$.

Comment: That seems to be what those equations suggest, but I don't know how to interpret the meaning of $X^+$. When we do $E[X^+]$, it's asking for the expectation of the positive part of $X$, but when we do $E[X | X > 0]$, isn't this also asking for the positive part of $X$? If so, why do the 2 have differing expectations?

Comment: @dd22205 $E[XI_{X>0}]$ is same as $EX^{+}$. But $E[X|{X>0}]$ is not the same. You have to divide by $PX>0$.